# multiple cascade paths, on update cascade

Tags: sql, path, relationship, cascade

I have a problem with sql server, when I want to have 3 table and make relationship between them, and change the "On Update" property to "cascade".

this problem happend when I want to save the diagram:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Company_Slave' on table 'Company' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

in this picture, I define my data base, FK and ....

[image: http://img.upload724.com/images/79103470449346687611.png]

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

A `FOREIGN KEY` in one table points to a **`PRIMARY KEY`** in another table. if you don't want to use `PRIMARY KEY` on other table in order to foreign key, you must be create unique index on the table.

**Second:**

you can create after trigger on Master table in order to develop on update cascade manually. In other word your foreign key between Company table and Master table created without on update cascade and then create following trigger on master to update company table after changed row in Master table.

```
create trigger triggername on dbo.[Master]
After Insert 
AS Begin
    Update Company
    Set MasterKey = I.MasterKey
    From Inserted I
    Inner join Deleted D on D.Code = I.Code
    Where Company.MasterKey = D.MasterKey
End
```